# What are the different missions in Pinball 3D Space Cadet?

Tags: microsoft-pinball

In the classic version of Pinball for Windows XP (image of the game below) the player after hitting certain targets would get a few missions. Some missions had the player **hit certain targets** for a number of hits, other missions had the player **re-enter the same place** where he first accepted the mission.

However, there were other different **types of missions** in this simple game. What were they? [image: Image 1]

Comment: Please try not to create new tags, rather use existing ones

Comment: @KenzoEngineer the already existing one is "pinball-microsoft" or something similar; that's like me creating a tag for dungeon-siege-microsoft;  It's redundant because the Dungeon Siege **only** came out for Windows (And that there are other pinball games for microsoft). pinball-microsoft could be changed or made a synonym of this, as this is the correct game title; or more accuratly, a standalone table of Full Tilt! Pinball

Comment: That's generally a meta question; if there's already a tag for a game, please use it instead of creating a new one.  If it needs to be changed, then make a case for it on meta.  Don't just create the tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are total of 17 different missions, each with different objectives, and only available to specific rank:

- Cadet

  1. Launch Training (top): **Pass** the *Launch Ramp* 3 times.
  2. Re-entry Training (middle): **Pass** the *Re-entry Lanes* 3 times.
  3. Target Practice (bottom): **Hit** the *Attack Bumpers* 8 times.
  4. Science Mission (all): **Hit** 9 *Drop Targets*.
- Ensign & Lieutenant

  1. Bug Hunt Mission (top): **Hit** 15 *targets (Drop and/or Hit*).
  2. Rescue Mission (middle): **Upgrade** *Flags*, then **enter** the *Hyperspace Kicker*.
  3. Alien Menace Mission (bottom): **Upgrade** the *Attack Bumpers*, then **hit** them 8 times.
  4. Secret Mission (all): **Enter** the *Yellow Wormhole*, then *Red Wormhole*, then *Green Wormhole*.
- Captain & Lt. Commander

  1. Stray Comet Mission (top): **Light** all 3 *Right Hazard Target Lights*, then **enter** the *Hyperspace Kicker*.
  2. Space Radiation Mission (middle): **Light** all 3 *Left Hazard Target Lights*, then **enter** any *Wormhole*.
  3. Black Hole Mission (bottom): **Upgrade** the *Engine Bumpers*, then **enter** the *Black Hole Kicker*.
  4. Cosmic Plague Mission (all): **Spin** *flags* 75 times, then **hit** *Space Warp Rollover*.
- Commander & Commodore

  1. Satellite Retrieval Mission (top): **Hit** the *Satellite Bumper* 3 times.
  2. Recon Mission (middle): **Pass** any of the *lanes* 15 times.
  3. Doomsday Machine Mission (bottom): **Send the Ball** through the *Out-Lanes* 3 times.
  4. Time Warp Mission (all): **Hit** the *Rebounds* 25 times, then **Enter** the *Launch Ramp* (promotion) or *Hyperspace Kicker* (rank demotion).
- Admiral & Fleet Admiral

  1. Cosmic Plague Mission (top, Captain's *all* mission)
  2. Secret Mission (middle, Ensign's *all* mission)
  3. Time Warp Mission (bottom, Commander's *all* mission)
  4. Maelstrom (all):

     1. **Hit** 3 *Drop Targets*.
     2. **Hit** 3 *Spot Targets*.
     3. **Send the Ball** through 5 *lanes*.
     4. **Shoot the ball** up the *fuel chute*.
     5. **Send the Ball** up the *launch ramp*.
     6. **Roll** a *Flag*.
     7. **Enter** any *Wormhole*.
     8. **Enter** the *Hyperspace Kicker*.

Source: [GameFAQs by froesch14](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/563047-3d-pinball-space-cadet/faqs/46514) | PINBALL.DOC mirrored on [Dokumen.tips](https://dokumen.tips/documents/3d-pinball-for-windows-space-cadet-table-rules-and-game-strategy.html).

Answer (score 1):

Background on this game. It was originally a part of a collection published by Maxis, of SimCity fame. [Full Tilt! Pinball](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Tilt!_Pinball) (Wikipedia) included three tables, one of them made it to Windows ME and XP Games packs.

As for missions, here is what I can recall:

- Launch: Lower left elevated ramp.
- Attack bumpers: ball hits against upper bumpers, and other targets *
- Orbits (I can't recall if this is an actual mission): Full orbits of back passageway around the top of the table
- Wormhole: (can't remember, but it was a thing)

Completing missions lights up the yellow ring in the center of the table, or maybe Blues first.  Wikipedia has some detail on the game mechanics.